# How to split string in bash and store the tokens in array

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash

I wrote this script to store some information about my machine such as the users and the running processes .

I tried to store the retrieved data into an array. To test array I printed the length of an array as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash


###################################################################################

openFilesCount=$(lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | wc -l);

openPortsCount=$(lsof -Fn -u teeba| sort  | uniq | grep /home | wc -l);

readingTime=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%T);

usersArr=$(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd);

pidsArr=$(ps axo pid);

###################################################################################

echo "${#usersArr[@]}";
```

The output is 1 ... although the users are three ? do I need to split the retrieved data on "\n" for example before store it in the array ? if yes , how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

```bsh
usersArr=($(awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd) )

for i in "${usersArr[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

here try this

```
 #!/bin/bash
 array=(elem1 elem2)
 #to print the size of the array
 echo "${array[@]}"  
 #to access an individual member
 echo "element number ${#array[@]}"
```

**Hope it helps**

Comment: see my update please!

Comment: There are few syntax errors in your code. Plz check before you post.

Comment: Sorry, no spaces in between the assingment operator and operands

Comment: [1] do not use space when declaring a variable, [2] array elements should be separated by space not comma *i.e.,* your `array = ("elem1", "elem2", "elem3")` should be `var=(elem1 elem2 elem3)` [3] array elements are `${array[@]}` not just `$array[@]`

Comment: yeah, i noticed. and I'm gonna correct that. no commas but spaces. Thanks